# Mark duplicate and answer

Tags: discussion

In [this](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50661/what-do-i-do-if-my-brakes-keep-squeaking-when-i-press-on-them-do-i-use-lubrican) question a user both marked as duplicate and answered.

The reasoning was users will not need to navigate to the duplicate.

My opinion is the target duplicate should be the master. People should navigate to the master. If there is an answer to add then add it to the master.  By not answering the master the master is diluted.

Users that find the master directly have no way to know other questions have answers.

There was already a comment don't lubricate. I suspected there was duplicate so I did not post as an answer.

Comment: This is relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled/

Comment: That link says don't answer if it is a duplicate

Comment: Good point, I've had this bugaboo too for quite a while.

Comment: Opinion from founder of StackExchange: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 3):

This question is a special case where something very silly and dangerous is asked a the answer is simply "**don't do it!**"

Ie is not relevant as a repository of expert knowledge but relevant as immediate help.

Comment: That immediate help was already the number 1 comment.  There was no urgency.

Comment: Is this some new rule that you have come up with, or is this a norm decided by the community? Do you have a link on meta that refers to these types of "emergencies"? The meta link provided, by jimchristie, in the comments does not seem to seem to state this at all. Where do we draw the line for answering idiot questions that are duplicates? "Is it ok if I cut my brake cables?", "Do I really need to tighten my wheel nuts?", "Should I assume other road users in cars can see me?", "Do I need lights at night?", etc... IMHO, a duplicate is a duplicate, and as such, should **not** be answered.